# PDO updating table with plus 1 value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

im trying to update my sql table with plus 1 incrementing value in order to calculate the page views. adding +1 everytime.

```
 $article = 1;
 $apikey = 22;
 // query
 $sql = "UPDATE apiapi 
    SET articles = articles +1
    WHERE apikey=?";
 $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array($article,$apikey));
```

the value dosent increase. it remain `1`.

Comment: Will this work ? `$q->execute(array($apikey));` ? Because I don't see any use of your `$article` variable

Comment: I will post this as an answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query only needs one parameter, there is no use for the `$article` variable.

`$q->execute(array($apikey));`